# Ineffecient continuous measurements in quantum measurement theory

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, measurements, density-operator, stochastic-processes

In a quantum measurement theory text "Quantum Measurement Theory and Applications" by K.Jacobs, he defines and explains the idea of a ***continuous measurement***, which is a measurement $$y = x_{true} + \xi$$ which takes place over a time $T$. We define the measurement result after $T$ as the limit $$y := \lim\limits_{\Delta \to 0} \sum_{n} \Delta y_n = \lim\limits_{\Delta t \to 0}[\sum_n x_{true}\Delta t + \beta \sum_n \Delta W_n]$$ Hence for each infinitesimal time-step $dt$, we have $$dy = x_{true}dt + \beta dW$$ where $dW$ is the Wiener increment (Brownian). When applied to quantum measurements, we get $$dy = \langle X \rangle dt + \frac{dW}{\sqrt{8k}}$$ It follows that in general the observers state of knowledge will be a density matrix, hence this leads to *the stochastic master equation* (SME): $$d \rho = -k[X,[X,\rho]]dt + \sqrt{2k}(X \rho - \rho X - 2 \langle X \rangle \rho)dW$$ In the description of ***inefficient measurements***: 
[image]
**Question:**
It states: "Of course, Alice's and Charlie's measurement results must have the same probability distribution or our description would be inconsistent" Can you see what the motivation is for this statement?

Comment: Welcome on Physics SE :) Please provide a source for the text and refrain from pasting text as an image - it is very unpleasant to deal with, e.g. for anyone who wants to copy parts for an answer

Comment: @TimDavids Charlie has access to both types of measurements, with strength k1 and k2, while Alice only has access to the k1 measurements. But their respective data on the k1 measurements must coincide - they must observe the same outcomes.

Comment: @udrv Thanks for your response, there's a small extra bit I added to the attachment. Could I back up and ask, why do we have to assume that Alice and Charlie have different initial states-of-knowledge, $\rho$ and $\tilde{\rho}$ respectively, why is it not suitable to state that they both start with the same state of knowledge $\rho$ (before measurement) and since Charlie has access to both measurements, he's state-of-knowledge would evolve in a different way?

Comment: @TimDavids 1) Please add at the very least a source for your text. 2) Their states of knowledge *do* evolve in a different way, since they obey different equations of motion. (Note the $\rho$ and $\tilde{\rho}$ are not just initial conditions, but time-dependent quantities.) But the point is that you cannot have two different predictions for physical observables, since in an actual measurement one only obtains one answer. So two different predictions means the theory is wrong.

Comment: @MarkMitchison Okay I have done that 1) as you requested. Even in a correct theory, if your one prediction is obtained using more information than another prediction surely it is then fine for them to be different. I don't therefore understand why $dy$ (Alice) and $dy_{1}$(Charlie) must have the same probability distribution based on that reason.

Comment: @TimDavids The key word here is coarse-graining: in other words, this is about the coarse-graining of the same given statistics, not about inaccessible essential details. Alice and Charlie acquire data on the statistics of the same observable, but at different "strengths". Think of strength as "resolution": Alice accumulates data at lower resolution, Charlie at higher resolution. But if Charlie extracts from his data set a subset corresponding to Alice's resolution, he must find the same statistical distribution as Alice, or else their observations (of the same process) are inconsistent.

Comment: @udrv Thanks I think that is a good explanation. Before equation (3.41), it states "We now make a measurement with strength $k_1$ in the first half of every time interval, and make the same measurement, but with the measurement strength $k_2$, in the second half of every time interval." But in equation (3.41) it seems that these sequential measurements are modeled as if they are made simultaneous, is this fine because $dt$ is assumed infinitesimal?

Comment: @TimDavids Yes, formally their statistics refer to the same infinitesimal time interval $dt$ even though it has been "split" into half-intervals.